# In regression, should we adjust for variables only associated with the independent or dependent variable?

Tags: regression, simulation, causality, confounding

I have recently been reading more about causal inference so am trying to conceptually think about model specification in more detail. From reading (e.g. [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1177/25152459221095823)), we adjust for confounders which, by definition, cause both the independent and dependent variable.

But how does adjusting for only variables associated with either the independent or dependent variable impact regression models? In my field of infant MRI imaging, age at scan is adjusted for in all studies because brain structure dramatically changes over the first weeks of life, so age at scan is strongly correlated with MRI feature (independent variable). But I would not expect age at scan to be correlated with e.g. developmental outcome at 1 year of age (dependent variable). To me, it doesn't make sense to adjust for age at scan as there is no causal pathway.

I run a basic simulation in R to see the effects, and age at scan is significant in the model and altered the coefficient for imaging feature (even when age at scan and outcome are uncorrelated).

What am I missing?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(faux)
library(GGally)

# define data
# age_scan strongly correlated with mri_feature
# mri_feature moderately correlated with outcome
# assume all had outcome at same date

set.seed(42)
dat <- rnorm_multi(
  n = 1000,
  mu = c(40, 0.4, 100),
  sd = c(3, 0.1, 15),
  r = c(0.8, 0, 0.5),
  varnames = c("age_scan", "mri_feature", "outcome")
)

glimpse(dat)
ggpairs(dat)

# linear models
m0 <- lm(outcome ~ mri_feature, data = dat)
m1 <- lm(outcome ~ mri_feature + age_scan, data = dat)

summary(m0)
summary(m1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that, since there is no connection with both the cause and the effect, it is impossible for age at scan to be a confounding variable. It cannot set up a backdoor path from the cause to the effect. The usual way to treat such variables is basically, "Eh." That is, you can include them in your model (thus conditioning on them) or not, but it shouldn't affect your results much at all.

Now you're saying that including it in the model *does* affect the outcome. To me that suggests two possibilities:

1. That there actually is a causal path from age at scan to developmental outcome, and that causal path would be simply $Z\to X\to Y,$ where $Z$ is the age at scan, $X$ is the MRI feature, and $Y$ is the developmental outcome. In such a case, we should not be surprised that $Z$ is correlated with $Y.$ The question is: should you include it in your model? I guess I would ask the question: by how much does the MRI feature coefficient change when you include vs. don't include $Z?$ If this really is the right causal diagram, then I would leave $Z$ out, but it shouldn't hurt to include it.
2. That the assumption that age at scan is not directly causally related to developmental outcome is flawed, and that in your graphical model you should also include the direct edge $Z\to Y,$ making $Z$ a true confounder: the backdoor path is $X\leftarrow Z\to Y$. In this scenario, it would be clear that you should include $Z$ in your model in order to condition on it.

In conclusion: you're probably safer including $Z$ in your model; in the second scenario you must, and in the first scenario it shouldn't hurt.